# How to save VBA variable in database?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form in [Access 2007](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access#Versions). In the form is a browse-file button. From the file-picker dialog the files name is saved in a [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) variable. And now to the question, **how do I save the file name stored in the VBA-variable in the database?**

The database has only one table.

Hope you can solve this, if not all information you need is provided, ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the form use this table as the Record Source? If so, where ever in your vba you apply the value to this variable, the just apply the same value to the appropriate field:

```
Me.TheFileNameField = TheFileNameVariable
```

You could also use an Update query, for example:

```
strSQL="UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeField='" & Replace(TheFileNameVariable,"'","''") & "'"
CurrentDB.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```